# NavMesh going in the ground

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, navmesh

I'm trying to do a navmesh. Everything seems to work fine exept that my character in almost completely under the ground. The ground is a plane with a mesh collider. I have baked it and checked my heigth mesh. My character has a rigidbody and a collider. What could be the problem ?

[image][image]

Comment: can you send a screenshot from your problem and Inspector settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your rigidBody **Kinematic** as navmesh and navmesh-Agent does not need physics to navigate your agent. make sure you object is grounded and be near of navigation mesh surface.

Comment: I already tried making it kinematic, no change. And would it still use gravity ?

Comment: @SamuelFyckes change base offset and height of your agent. that will be okay.

Comment: Thanks, it aactually worked, but now gravity dont affect him, I cant even move him on the yaxis on runtime.

Comment: Also, doesn't seems like he want to jump on blocks, scale of 1 and i tried changing the obstacle height he can jump to other numbers

Comment: @SamuelFyckes it all depends on your design. you shouldnt handle all functions on one object. most of the time navigation is on a base parent object then character model and animations are on a sub object. if you want physics it should be handled in sub object. an object cant be handled wit physics engine and transformation both